# how to control input value be integer in reactive form

Tags: input, angular-reactive-forms

```
<input
  #valueRef
  tabindex="1"
  type="number"
  step="1"
  name="value"
  id="value"
  placeholder="Enter value"
  class="form-control"
  formControlName="value"
  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && adjForm.controls['value'].errors && !this.data.isAdjAccount }"
/>
```

I set input step as 1, but it still supports to input decimal, what I want to show is: when you open this from, and enter value in this input box, it forbids user to enter decimals, only integer is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter value" id="txtvalueRef"   name="valueRef" #valueRef="ngModel"          pattern="[0-9]*">

   <div [hidden]="valueRef.valid || valueRef.pristine"    class="alert alert-danger">
            <div [hidden]="!valueRef.hasError('pattern')">Items should be only numbers</div>
    </div>
```